# IE не выполняет JQuery (Не удалось получить свойство "createElement" ссылки, значение которой не определено или является NULL)

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

IE не выполняет код JQuery, подскажите в чем может быть проблема. 
Хром, мозила работает. 
Неделю вторую уже бьюсь, заранее спасибо.

**P.S.** 
Если нужно будет предоставить исходники, либо другую информацию, пишите. 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Добавили бы код, который выбрасывает это исключение, было бы полезно. И версию jQuery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Версии от IE 7 до 9 весьма печально относятся к некоторым функциям JQuery, Ajax и прочим новациям сатаны, поэтому было решено поставить версию, через мета тег.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=необходимая версия" />
```

Comment: И как связаны между собой `Версии от IE 7 до 9 весьма печально` и IE11 показанный на картинке в вопросе?

Comment: @Visman Установленная версия IE 11, 
в режиме документов по умолчанию использовалась 7,
решил предоставить версию браузера, по причине того, что не знал что можно было предоставить, в л
юбом случае сделал приписку в вопросе после P.S.